# Looking for tool to do PXE boot

Tags: untagged

Im having issues with my new SCCM R3 and PXE boot, and i was wondering if a tool that allows me to do a fake pxe boot ( IE be a PXE boot client ) but with lots of logging exists?

I know i can find a hub, and then but it inbetween and wireshark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to PXE boot a virtual machine (and then use wireshark, etc, to trace the traffic over your physical interface).

Answer (score 2):

Just something recently i had an issue with, not directly with SCCM but with WDS. Remember the DCHP must have the PXE service added and also remember PXE boot do not work well across subnets unless you have solid configs on your switches for bootP relay agents.

Specifically on Cisco switches: the IP helper-addresses can direct UDP broadcasts to a unicast or broadcast IP address. It is not recommended to use the IP helper-address to forward UDP broadcasts from one subnet to the broadcast address of another subnet, due to the large amount of broadcast flooding that may occur.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to install netmon 3.4 on your sccm server!